# Is it possible (and how) to get comments left on youtube on any account/channel?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to use this code `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=snippet&id=zwGBTcIHN0U&key={YOUR_API_KEY}` (clearly with a proper key) to get comments left on a random channel, random video but I get an empty list as result:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#commentListResponse",
 "etag": "\"tbWC5XrSXxe1WOAx6MK9z4hHSU8/pGLBhpjR05yQoJV31WoAx2PEFVw\"",
 "items": []
}
```

I can't find proper documentation beside the official one: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list#try-it

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'd do commentThreads.list with channelid and/or videoId to get threads then get comments under that threads.

You are setting videoId to commentId field in your example.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if there is a page with a summary of what is possible to publicly get through the API? For example: I can get some comments on a video, but I can't get the subscribers of a channel which is not mine?